# Como acessar link com parâmetro através formulário em html ou html5?

Tags: html, html5, formulário

Eu tenho o seguinte código em html.

```
<form action="http://www.meulinkqueseraredirecionado.com/namer/">
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="Acessar" />
</form>
```

Eu quero que assim que o usuario clicar no botão "Acessar", após inserir um numero no input "text", ele acesse o link "http://www.meulinkqueseraredirecionado.com/namer/numeroInserido"

Como é feito em HTML ou HTML5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando apenas JavaScript, podes fazer assim:

```js
document.getElementById('enviar').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var param = document.getElementById('param');
  var act = document.getElementById('form');
  act.action += param.value;
  window.open(act.action, '_blank');
  act.action = "http://www.meusite.com/";
});
```

```html
<form action="http://www.meusite.com/" id="form">
  <input type="text" id="param">
  <input type="submit" id="enviar">
</form>
```

Ao clicar no botão enviar, o JavaScript irá pegar o valor do campo parâmetro e adicionar ao valor do atributo `action` do formulário.

*Observação: No snippet do StackOverflow é bloqueado o submit do formulário.*

Comment: Agora não está redirecionando

Comment: Faltou apenas adicionar no javascript após o `act.action += param.value;` , o código pra redirecionar `window.open(act.action, '_blank');`

Comment: @TiagoFerezin depois de chamar o `windows.open`, você volta o `action` para o valor inicial. Legal, gostei! Muito obrigado pela edição.